# Why the input is undefined?

Tags: reactjs

What I'm trying to do is to add and remove input fields.

```
export default function AddInput() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ items: "" }]);

  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { items: "" }]);
  };

  const handleItemChanged = (event, index) => {
    const { items, value } = event.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][items] = value;
    setInputList(list);

    console.log('list', list)
    console.log('value', value)
    console.log('items', items)
  };

  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };


return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {inputList.map((o, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={"item-" + i}>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={o.items}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    onChange={event => handleItemChanged(event, i)}
                  />
                </div>
              </td>
           </tr>
          )
         )}
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that when I type a word inside the input, it won't write anything.
In my console, it shows me the items is `undefinded`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is the possible values for items in side input?,is it a text that user typed? or an array?if an array then what is the value? can you give me an example?

Comment: the reason items is undefined because there is no member called items in event.target that you are tying to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see you are trying to store values inside multiple inputbox and want to render it

**what are you doing wrong?**

1.trying to get items from `event.target`

2 assigning value to undefined member like  `list[index][items] = value;`

**So,what to do to make it work?**

i assume items is just a text that you get from inputbox,if its so then,

you can correct the input handler like this

```
const handleItemChanged = (event, index) => {
//old code,there is no node named items in event.target
//const { items, value } = event.target;
const value=event.target.value;
const list = [...inputList];
//old code,since items is undefined you cant access it this way
//list[index][items] = value;
//the correct way to do it
list[index].items=value;
setInputList(list);

console.log('list', list)
console.log('value', value)
console.log('items', list[index].items)

};
```